# How to reference specific levels of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object with the following structure:

```
obj = {
    foo: 'bar',
    data: {
        hello: this.foo
    }
}
```

However, `this` in the 2nd level is always the `Window` object. How can I reference `foo` properly?

**NOTE**

I know I can put the object into a "class" and referencer the property with `self`or something. This is not an option for me. The object must be a standalone JSON object.

Comment: The value of *this* within an execution context is set by the call. How are you attempting to access the property? I guess by "JSON object" you actually mean an [*Object initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) or literal.

Comment: If `obj = {foo: 'bar',data: {}}; obj.data.hello = obj.foo;` isn't an option, I'm not aware of any way to do that in object declaration.

Comment: just to mention that the structure you have provided is a standard Javascript Object ... and second this depends on the context ... because it is in main context it is always window

Comment: @Reflective—it depends on how *this* has been set **within** an execution context.

Comment: that's what i told :) in code provided it is executed in main context which is window

Comment: @RobG this isnt a duplicate of that question. I'm not asking how to use the `this` keyword. I'm asking how to reference specific layers of an object. This question could very well have a difference answer than the "duplicate" you have linked to.

Comment: @dopatraman: I am not sure this question is entirely clear. Could you perhaps add a JS Fiddle to illustrate what you are trying to do, or add more code to the question? As it stands, the `this` value will vary depending on where this code is executed.

Comment: This question has at least 3 week points: 1) There's nothing related to JSON 2) duplicating data in data structures sooner ot later will lead you to inconsistency - wrong approach 3) you can not use slef- referencing of an stil undefined object - so you can not slef-reference an object in it's definition. It's clear.

Comment: If this was on the same level you could use a getter like this: `obj=({foo:'bar', get data(){return this.foo;}})`. Because in your case `data` is its own object `this` can never reference the `obj` object inside `data`.

Comment: @dopatraman—Bergi has changed the duplicate, whatever. There are two issues: attempting to use *this* in a context where it can't be set and attempting to reference object properties defined within the same object literal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.foo`, use obj.foo. Javascript almost always thinks `this` is the global/window. If that doesn't work, I would recommend creating another variable.

Good luck!

Comment: I get an error telling me that `obj` is undefined. I guess it makes sense because obj hasnt be defined yet?

Comment: obj is still not existing so this will result an error

Comment: Not "window/document" but *global/window* object. ;-)

Comment: @dopatraman Look at my comment to your question of how you must write to get that to work.

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot to put in extra info!

Comment: @some there is an option, just you have to mess around a bit with the code.

Comment: @Iamaregistereduser What do you mean? `obj = {foo: 'bar',data: {hello:obj.foo}};` does not work (unless `obj` is already defined, and then `hello` would get the data from that object and not from the object that is begin created)

Comment: @some If you create another variable. For instance `var hello=obj.foo` Other than that, you are correct: there is no other way.